# I have used dropzone.js at many places inside my project, however i want to limit the number of files at only one place

Tags: dropzone.js

I have used dropzone.js at many places inside my project, however i want to limit the number of files at only one place. I have applied the script but it gets applied to every page where i am using dropzoneJS

Comment: Solved it myself. It seems to work when you remove the corresponding id from HTML FORM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work when you remove the corresponding id from HTML FORM.